# Actual and formal method lists vary in length

Tags: java, boolean

Afternoon! I'm having some trouble with my boolean method in the class "Television". All I'm basically trying to accomplish is whenever that method is called, I want the value of powerStatus to be switched.

```
/**
 * @author Thomas Samuel
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 22/02/2017
 * <h1>Television Remote / Lab Sheet 2</h1>
 * <p1>The following program is made for a television remote to control power, channel information, and volume.</p1>
*/
class Television {
    Television Television = new Television();
    boolean powerStatus = false;
    int currentChannel;
    int currentVolume = 50;
    boolean togglePower(boolean powerStatus) {
        if(powerStatus = false) {
            powerStatus = true;
        } else if(powerStatus = true) {
            powerStatus = false;
        }
        return powerStatus;
    }
    boolean getPowerStatus(boolean powerStatus) {
    return powerStatus;
    }
}
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Television.togglePower();
    }
}
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

```
Controller.java:27: error: method togglePower in class Television cannot be applied to given types;
        Television.togglePower();
                  ^
  required: boolean
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Comment: you have **not passed** a `boolean` argument when you call the `togglePower` method.

Comment: `class Television {  Television Television = new Television(); ...` Why are you instantiating an instance of `Television` as a non-static member of itself? Why are you naming a variable the same as its class? These are both indicators that you have not understood some fundamental principles, and make your code very hard to read.  For example, in your main method `Television.togglePower();` looks like a static method call but it's not.  It works only because of your overloading of the name `Television`.

Comment: And next up, you're going to get a message that a non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Also, `if(powerStatus = false) {` is SETTING `powerStatus` to `false` instead of comparing it to false.  You need `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Or better yet just use `variable` or `!variable` and forget the operator all together.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because you call `togglePower` with no parameter, but this method expects a `boolean` parameter.

Change your `togglePower` method to take no parameter, since it already owns the `powerStatus` variable :

```
    boolean togglePower() {

        powerStatus = !powerStatus;

        return powerStatus;
    }
```

In the same way, it makes no sense for a simple getter method to take a parameter, so try:

```
    boolean getPowerStatus() {
        return powerStatus;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please study this code carefully to see what you need to change

```
class Television {
    boolean powerStatus = false;
    int currentChannel;
    int currentVolume = 50;
    boolean togglePower() {
        powerStatus = !powerStatus;
        return powerStatus;
    }
    boolean getPowerStatus() {
        return powerStatus;
    }
}
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Television tv = new Television();
        tv.togglePower();
        System.out.println(tv.getPowerStatus());
    }
}
```

I moved the instantiation into the main method and changed `togglePower` to use logical "not" to toggle the boolean.

Comment: Your code is not so good.  Your getPowerStatus method is currently returning the value passed in to the method, and your togglePower method isn't toggling the power on the TV.

Comment: Sorry I neglected to remove the unneeded parameters from the method declarations. Fixed.